# Using two different things two check if user is allowed to login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two different types of users in my laravel application 'S' and 'D', for type D I need to send a verification mail upon register, and for type 'S' I need to manually approve the user first and then  send him the verification mail. So user type 'D' should be approved by default. So I did this in my Auth\RegisterController:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{ 
    if($data['u_type'] == 'D'){
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'u_type'=> $data['u_type'],
            'token' => str_random(25),
            'avatar'=> str_random(5),
            'approved'=>true
        ]);
    }else
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'u_type'=> $data['u_type'],
            'token' => str_random(25),
            'avatar'=> str_random(5),
            'approved'=>false
        ]);
    }
```

The problem occurs when I register, both of the user types have approved set to null,what am I doing wrong.
And please also check the following function.This function should check both the conditions if user logs in its in LoginController

```
    protected function authenticated(Request $request){

    $user = User::where('email','=', $request->email)->first();
    if($user->token!=null){
      if($user->approved == 0){
        Auth::logout();
        return back()->with('info','Account not approved yet, please 
         contact admin');   
      }
      Auth::logout();
      return back()->with('info','Account not verified, please check 
       your email '.$user->email);
    }
    else{
      Auth::login($user);
      return redirect()->back();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to simplify your proccess:

**Auth\RegisterController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{ 
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'u_type'=> $data['u_type'],
            'token' => str_random(25),
            'avatar'=> str_random(5),
            'approved'=> $data['u_type'] == 'D' ? true: false
        ]);
}
```

One thing I believe you should have is: in your database, set the column 'approved' default to false and not nullable.
One other thing that maybe happening is that you may not have the variable 'approved' in the `$fillable` in User model.

Your User model should have something like this:

```
$fillable = ['name','lname','email','password','u_type','token','avatar','approved'];
// $guarded = ['password']; or even $hidden = ['password']
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#included-authenticating

**LoginController**

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request){

    $user = User::where('email','=', $request->email)->first();

    //There is no need to validate the token, unless you really want it to
    if($user->approved) {
      Auth::attempt($user); 
      //Or Auth::login($user);
      return redirect()->back();
      //Redirect back may redirect you to a place where you may not want it, depending on the url's that you hit previously when loading a page, a redirect to a certain url, usually home, is more effective
    }
    else{ 
        //Token will be filled with a random string whenever the account is created, so validation if token is null is really needed.
        //What you may need is to save information about if an email was or not sent to the user and if it did sent, it shows different errors.
        return back()->with('info','Account not approved yet, please contact admin');   
        //No need to Auth::logout if he didn't managed to login. Either he's logged or he's not
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you please tell me if the authenticated() function from logincontroller is okay? because it seems to behave unusually

Comment: I had set a default value to 0 in my table.I thought this might override that. Now i set that to null and it seems to be working OK

Comment: default value is applied if you don't send a value in approved. Eloquent won't fill approved if it isn't in the fillables array of your model. Null won't exactly solve it but that now depends on how you want to manage the code. Answer is updated, with the authenticated.

Comment: I need to validate the token as well in order to restrict their logins. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Confused about how you're going to do that with str_random but hey, if it works, awsome!

Comment: Upon Verification the token is set to null so all I do is check if the token is null or not, now that you have pointed that out seems like using the same approach as verified would be better will look into it.